# Expo Build Error with code that should be working?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I have a react native application that I have been working on. I want to do an expo build to submit for review through apple. Every time i run the expo build. It sets to the same line of code and breaks for some reason and I am not sure why it is breaking. There is nothing wrong with my code. I tested it and double tested it and it works properly. I am not sure what to do at this point.

Here is the code I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'
import axios from 'axios'

import PropertySampleComponent from '../components/GeneralComponents/PropertySampleComponent'
import ContactAgentComponent from '../components/PropertyScreenComponents.js/ContactAgentComponent'

import { extendedPropertOptions, singlePropertyOptions } from '../../zillow.js'

const ContactAgentScreen = ({route}) => {

  const [addressLookup, setAddressLookup] = useState('')
  const [currentHome, setCurrentHome] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    if(route.params?.zpid){
      getPropertyDetails(route.params.zpid)
    }
  }, [])

  const newSearch = () => {
    extendedPropertOptions.params.location = addressLookup
    axios.request(extendedPropertOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        Object.keys(response.data).length == 1 ? getPropertyDetails(response.data.zpid) : console.log('no detail found')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  const getPropertyDetails = (zpid) => {
    singlePropertyOptions.params.zpid = zpid
    axios.request(singlePropertyOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        setCurrentHome(response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Connect With An Agent</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <Feather style={styles.chevronDown} size={20} name='search'/>
        <TextInput 
          value={addressLookup}
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={setAddressLookup}
          placeholder={'Enter an address'}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.searcingContainer} onPress={() => {newSearch()}}>
          <Text style={styles.searchSubmit}>Search</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {
        Object.keys(currentHome).length == 0 ? null : <View style={styles.property}><PropertySampleComponent item={currentHome}/></View>
      }
      <ContactAgentComponent currentHome={currentHome}/>
    </View>
  )
}

...
```

here is the error I am getting with expo build:

```
› Executing Reipp » Bundle React Native code and images
    the transform cache was reset.
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reipp-gorbnnjknomygnfxwixidlmwggov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Reipp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Reipp.build/Release-iphoneos/Reipp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Reipp' from project 'Reipp')
▸ (1 failure)
2022-09-25 19:46:53.593 xcodebuild[4248:12379] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-09-25 19:46:53.593 xcodebuild[4248:12379] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-09-25 19:46:53.646 xcodebuild[4248:12379] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
2022-09-25 19:46:53.646 xcodebuild[4248:12379] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
2022-09-25 19:46:53.646 xcodebuild[4248:12379] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
2022-09-25 19:46:53.646 xcodebuild[4248:12379] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Reipp-gorbnnjknomygnfxwixidlmwggov/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Reipp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Reipp.build/Release-iphoneos/Reipp.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Reipp' from project 'Reipp')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           Build environment           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version | 2.206.1                 |
| sdk         | iPhoneOS15.5.sdk        |
+-------------+-------------------------+
Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
sure your project is set up correctly.
fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[stderr] [!] Error building the application - see the log above
error Unable to resolve module ../../zillow.js from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/src/screens/ContactAgentScreen.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * zillow.js(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * zillow.js/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
   7 | import ContactAgentComponent from '../components/PropertyScreenComponents.js/ContactAgentComponent'
   8 |
>  9 | import { extendedPropertOptions, singlePropertyOptions } from '../../zillow.js'
     |                                                                ^
  10 |
  11 | const ContactAgentScreen = ({route}) => {
  12 |.
Error: Unable to resolve module ../../zillow.js from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/src/screens/ContactAgentScreen.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * zillow.js(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * zillow.js/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
   7 | import ContactAgentComponent from '../components/PropertyScreenComponents.js/ContactAgentComponent'
   8 |
>  9 | import { extendedPropertOptions, singlePropertyOptions } from '../../zillow.js'
     |                                                                ^
  10 |
  11 | const ContactAgentScreen = ({route}) => {
  12 |
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at /Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/Reipp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
info 
Error: Fastlane build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run fastlane" and "Xcode Logs" phases for more information.
Fastlane errors in most cases are not printed at the end of the output, so you may not find any useful information in the last lines of output when looking for an error message.
```

[image: File Structure]

[image: Expo Build Error]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing comes to my mind is that your import is not correct at line 9. Please check if zillow.js is in correct order. I cannot suggest any solution cause i am not able to see your folder structure.

Comment: I tried and retried to make sure the import is correct like 6 times. I am not getting any issue with that line of code. Here is the github link https://github.com/ojandali93/Reipp-Mobile it is really annoying at this point. I even ```console.log``` the two objects and they displayed correctly so I know they imported correctly